Aframe Resonance Audio Component not playing audio in VR
I'm using the aframe-resonance-audio-component https://github.com/adammarcwilliams/aframe-resonance-audio-component to create an audio experience.
However when i start the experience in Chrome on my desktop it plays the sound while experiencing it in the Quest browser i cannot ear any sound.
Is there a limit on how many sources I can have at the same time using resonance audio? Or it could be the browser because I tried with another one (Wolwic) and it works.
The context is said to be correctly started and infact it works on a normal pc. The problem is just on the quest browser
